# Number every second page, text on first page, pictures on the second

Tags: pdftex, page-numbering, floating

I have a friend who is face with more and more absurd formatting rules in her thesis. In the end, the thesis should be printed on every second page. This is OK, and has nothing  to do with `LaTeX`.

But there also must not be any images or tables inside the actual text. Instead, images and texts should always be on the back page of the page they belong to, and these pages should then not be numbered of course.

Example:

```
|=========|=========|
|         | text    |
|         | text    |
|         | see A1  |
|         |  [p23]  |
|=========|=========|

|=========|=========|
|         |         |
|   [A1]  |  text   |
|         |  text   |
|         |  [p24]  |
|=========|=========|

|=========|=========|
|         |  text   |
|         |  text   |
|         |  see T2 |
|         |  [p25]  |
|=========|=========|

|=========|=========|
|         |         |
|   [T2]  | text    |
|         |         |
|         |  [p26]  |
|=========|=========|
```

Is there a clever way to accomplish this this? I just do not know how to deal with this stuff, except for manually working with weird "do not number this", `\clearpage` and dangerous manual floats.

Comment: You can do this with parcol.  See section 9 (page 34).  The one difference is that the paired pages have the same number (otherwise the \listoffigures would be have no page numbers listed).

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate my comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% fake text

\globalcounter*
 
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}[1]{2}
\switchcolumn
 \lipsum[1-4]
\switchcolumn*% place figure beside or after this page
\begin{figure}[p]
  \rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\end{figure}
\switchcolumn
  \lipsum[5-12]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

---

I created a new page counter and redefined `\pagestyle{plain}` to remove the page numbers from the "odd" pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% fake text

\newcounter{abspage}
\setcounter{abspage}{1}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\stepcounter{abspage}}

\globalcounter*

\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo% fancyhdr is for wimps
  \let\@oddhead\@empty\def\@oddfoot{\ifodd\c@abspage
    \else\reset@font\hfil\thepage\hfil\fi}%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
  
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}[1]{2}
\switchcolumn
 \lipsum[1-4]
\switchcolumn*% while not necessary, it helps to switch columns once per page
\begin{figure}[p]
  \rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\end{figure}
\switchcolumn
  \lipsum[5-12]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have a look for it.